# Test of notification mechanisms

Tags: discussion

(This question first appeared on our main site).  It tests a hypothesis about user notification.  We were wondering whether inserting an "@" when *editing* a question would cause the user to be notified.  Because notifications work differently on the meta site (where this thread belongs), it is crucial to post it (albeit temporarily) on our main site.

@jbowman, concerning your comment at [Frequentism and priors](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29835/frequentism-and-priors#comment57017_29835): have you been notified now?

@whuber, this is a self-notification.

chl and mbq, you are mentioned without an "@" in case we need to re-test the editing mechanism.

Comment: I am going to use it to see if I can notify myself :P @Procrastinator

Comment: Not constructive, too localized, not a real question AND off topic all at once! ;)

Comment: I don't believe the @ notification works *at all* outside of the comments.

Comment: Nice edits @Procrastinator (lol...). Who is upvoting this?

Comment: I haven't been notified, not for this one nor for the Frequentism question one.  I'll upvote this!

Comment: You guys are having too much fun with this. ;-)

Comment: @Procrastinator, did you create the knowledge-discovery tag just for this question?

Comment: Well, the self-notification didn't work either.  I think we've learned what we needed to: "@" is for comments (and maybe chat--maybe there's another experiment worth making there?), but does not appear to work within questions.  (We probably could have looked that up on SO meta, but it sure is more fun to take the radically empirical route, and didn't take any longer...)  I'll migrate this question to our meta site now.

Comment: Sorry, @Procrastinator, your tag edits seem to have been wiped out by the migration.  They're still visible in the old closed version.

Comment: @whuber: Yes, I forgot about chat! I know for a fact that on occasion someone will cite a user in a question or answer and in the instances I've been cited, I've never received a notification even when I've participated in the comment stream below.

Comment: My understanding of the notification is that it's a local lookup from the comment stream, not a global lookup. That makes sense given that user names do.not have to be unique. I've sometimes wanted a global lookup feature like @user1234 where 1234 is the user id to notify a participant. My guess is they purposefully don't do.this so that whuber and other prolific users don't get a deluge of look-at-my-thread-please notifications.